# Tkinter Button and Entry Issues

Tags: python, tkinter, beautifulsoup

This line of code is supposed to show a button in the Weather Zip window. The problem is that only the WeatherZip entry shows and that the button does not.
Here is the sample code:

```
  Weather = Tk()
  Weather.geometry('350x200') 
  Weather.title("Weather Finder")

  Label(Weather, text = "Enter Zip").grid(row = 0, column = 0)

  ZipCode = Entry(Weather)
  ZipCode.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

  zip_code = ZipCode.get() 

  ZipButton = Button(Weather, text='CHECK WEATHER!', commmand=checkWeather(zip_code))
  ZipButton.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
```

I believe this won't be able to be solved just with this snipit, so I here is a link with all the code. https://hastebin.com/ibodatifem.py

The error is

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Python Stuff\Something.py", line 18, in checkWeather
    place = content.findAll("header", {"class": "loc-container"})[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Python Stuff\Something.py", line 60, in WeatherDef
    ZipButton = Button(Weather, text='CHECK WEATHER!', commmand=checkWeather(ZipCode.get())
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Python Stuff\Something.py", line 31, in checkWeather
    temp = 'Temp: ' + content.findAll("div", {"class": "today_nowcard-temp"})[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am very stupid, so help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
GetRektOrElse

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the button command like this line. You can't pass args the way you are doing it use lambda instead.

```
ZipButton = Button(Weather, text='CHECK WEATHER!', command=lambda: checkWeather(ZipCode.get())
```

Comment: So, after I had tried code it had released another error, this time it says https://hastebin.com/ubafalemit.py

Comment: @GetRektOrElse if you have new problem then create new question on new page.

Comment: @GetRektOrElse in new erorr you have three `m` in word `command` - and this makes problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! You both are very helpful!